# Filter objects if array has no value in php

Tags: php

I want to only show the objects that have a specific value.

Case:
I have two comments, one have images and the other one not.

How can I get only the objects that have array "field_comment_image" values??

[image]

I'm trying:

```
foreach($comments as $comment) {
    if(isset($comment->field_comment_image)){
    dpm($comment);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following:

```
foreach($comments as $comment) {
    if(!empty($comment->field_comment_image)){
    dpm($comment);
    }
}
```

Instead of checking if the value `isset` try checking if it's empty. The field is always set (if I understand correctly from your image).

Comment: Thanks so much! I was in the noob way :P

Comment: @JulianChabrillon Haha no worries :)